# Cannot find Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, t4

I am doing some work with T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) and am trying to get to a point where I can create my own custom text template host. However, all of that relies on the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating** assembly and I cannot find it on my system!

I first tried adding a reference to the assembly in Visual Studio, but the assembly for **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating** is not listed under the .NET tab.

I then took a look in the *%WINDIR%/Assembly* directory and found an entry for **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating**. However, when I try and browse to this location and add the assembly in Visual Studio, nothing happens.

Has anybody else had this problem? According to MSDN tuts it sounds like this assembly should be included with Visual Studio (and I have VS 2003, 2005, and 2008 installed).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have the Visual Studio SDK installed. Here is where the assembly is physically installed on my system:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.dll.

It does show up in the Add Reference dialog normally.

Comment: Thanks, Oleg. I installed the VS2008 SDK and now I can reference the assembly. By the way, your blog has been a great resource to me for T4. I really appreciate all your work!

Comment: With VS2010 SP1 installing the SDK is still the solution. They appended 10.0 to the names of the files when adding references but the Namespaces seem to be the same still.

Comment: I think Visual Studio only shows the compatible assemblies. Change the .NET Framework version if needed.

Answer (score 9):

**Visual Studio 2012** SDK folder is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0`

Answer (score 6):

In the (new) GAC:

VS 2012 (v11.0)

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.11.0\v4.0_11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

VS 2013 (v12.0)

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.12.0\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Answer (score 4):

[These](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.14.0) assemblies have been available for a while now as NuGet packages.

This allows for better dependency management via NuGet.

Comment: I can't seem to find documentation on how to actually use these - do you have a reference or example?

Comment: It's here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/writing-a-t4-text-template?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio 2015** folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0

Answer (score 0):

I have Visual Studio 2008 installed (without the SDK) and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.dll` is in the following location on my machine:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.1`