# Could not find Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, t4

When I invoke the Add Reference dialog, I got this:
[image: TextTemplating]

I have both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 installed on the computer. What's wrong?

Comment: have look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559027/cannot-find-microsoft-visualstudio-texttemplating-assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bug of Visual Studio. However, I can directly edit csproj file to include this assembly by adding a simple reference:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This works because the assembly is already in GAC just like other assemblies (e.g., System, System.Data).

Answer (score 3):

You have to reference it from its file path by using browse:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.11.0\v4.0_11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\

Also, this tripped me up, make sure you:

Reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.11.0 if your project is targeting .net 4.5.

Reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0 if your project is targeting .net 4.0.