# Where can I find definitions of the GetSourceSchemaTypes routine?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm digging deeper into Entity Framework Templating and want to find out more about the GetSourceSchemaTypes routine, used here as an example

```
foreach (EntityType entity in GetSourceSchemaTypes<EntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
{
}
```

It appears to be part of the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating` namespace but I can't find that on MSDN.

I'm looking for something specific but the answer may be revealed in the definition of this routine.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`GetSourceSchemaTypes` (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating` namespace) can be found in the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating** assembly (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.dll) delivered with the [Visual Studio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb166441%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can use a .NET decompiler to have a look at the code.

ILSpy is free and works fine: http://ilspy.net/

---

If you have any difficulty to locate the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating** assembly, you can have a look at this question: [Cannot find Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559027/cannot-find-microsoft-visualstudio-texttemplating-assembly) :)

For example, if you use Visual Studio 2012 the assembly may be here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0

PS: I don't understand why this answer is downvoted, there is nothing wrong with decompiling.. It's a nice tool to improve understanding of something..